# Symfony 4 assets response error in dev , require which php extension?

Tags: php, symfony

In symfony I use `bin/console server:run` all resources response is invalid ~
 example:
[css response info by 'bin/console'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHNGa.png)
This is return a text and has not response header.
But when I use `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public`, it is worked!
[css response info by 'php -S'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYlT7.png)

And there are some logs is samed in terminal [They are all response 200!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eSZS.png).

I think the reason is that I have some php extension not istalled.
So I `composer require req-checker`,But there is not required [symfony required check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNSOQ.png)

So who can tell me I will require which extension can fixed it.
Thanks!

Comment: The browser is caching the responses.  That is good.  It makes your page run faster.  Caching means that the browser saves the file and the next time you request it, the browser delivers it from the cache instead of going to the server to get it.  Everything is okay.

Comment: https://medium.com/@codebyamir/a-web-developers-guide-to-browser-caching-cc41f3b73e7c

Comment: But it seems not cache, if it is cache will return 304 code , but it have not response code in firefox.And use Chrome it will return 404 and with that message 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE'; thank you

Comment: I maybe misunderstanding, but I do believe this is a browser cache issue https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor/request_list

Comment: OK,Thank you, I am going to try it